# Creating polygons based on Sum of point data

Tags: qgis, spatial-analyst, network-analyst

I'm not sure if this is possible? But can you run a tool, or code this in python, that would generate polygons from adding up point data.

Sort of like convex/concave hull but instead of tracing points with similar attribute data, it would trace points by similar location, adding up an attribute field, and stop once it hits a certain number, then repeat. Until all points are inside an individual polygon.

For example, I have building centroids with the amount of units in each building, I want to create polygons around centroids until it reaches 180 units. Then start a new polygon, creating multiple polygons in a area.

I have been trying different tools.

Comment: What tools and precise steps have you already tried?  For focused Q&A I suggest taking the tool you most want to use first and exploring where you are stuck in detail with this community.

Comment: You could start with Thiessen polygons http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00080000001m000000 but dissolving to precisely 180 units sounds a little more difficult. Dissolve http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000005n000000 has a statistics field but will only aggregate polygons with matching unique dissolve field, populating this is the real problem. Perhaps you could remove very large Thiessen polygons, dissolve and Dice to get a workable output, not guaranteed to be 180 units but may fulfil the ultimate goal of creating manageable areas.

Comment: I don't think this question should have been put on hold, as it is an interesting question with a specific answer: How does one generate Thiessen Polygons, but instead of one point per polygon, we want 180.

Comment: @J.W.Powell this question has been put on hold because it's a *very* complex problem with a complicated answer with no evidence of user code to build upon. It has been tagged QGIS but also spatial and network analyst which are Esri extensions so we're unsure of how to continue with that ambiguity. If such polygons can be created they would not be Thiessen polygons as, by definition, each Thiessen polygon contains precisely one point not an aggregation of points whose sum of UNITS attribute equals 180; and what happens if that number cannot be reached with the available polygons?

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. The closest we came to obtaining any kind of results was sorting the lat/long points from smallest to largest...we thought that would make point 1 closest to point 2 and so on. Then we created an array in python that added up the living unit data field in the sorted points layer until it reached 180 and gave all those points a similar group number and then it repeated. Until all points had a group number. Then ran a convex hull on the group field, creating polygons. We found out Those polygons were skinny horizontal groups....not what we wanted.